# OpenMP matrix multiplication takes more time than expected

Tags: c, openmp

I am writing an OpenMP program to multiply two matrices. The idea is that each thread calculates some part of each cell's result. Then, after that, I add those results for each cell to get the result of multiplication.

The problem is that the program takes a lot of time when I use large matrices (512x512 or 1024x1024). Indeed, when I used a matrix of size 1024x1024 using 5 threads, it took 43 seconds, while with 1 thread, it took 14 seconds.

I am thinking It might be the critical section causing huge delays.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int ** make_array(int n,int m,int f)
{
    int i,j;
    int *linear, **arr;
    linear = malloc(sizeof(int)*m*n);
    arr = malloc(sizeof(int *)*n);
    for(i = 0;i<n;++i) arr[i] = &linear[i*m];
    if(f == 0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        for(j=0;j<m;++j) arr[i][j] = 0;
        return arr;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        for(j=0;j<m;++j) arr[i][j] = 1+i;
    return arr;
}

void printMat(int **mat, int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n;++j)
        {
            printf("%d ",mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;            /// matrix dimension


    scanf("%d", &n);
    double TIME = 0;
    int **a,**b,**c;
    a = make_array(n,n,1);
    b = make_array(n,n,1);
    c = make_array(n,n,0);

    int i,j,k;

    #pragma omp parallel private(i,j,k) shared(a,b,c,TIME)
    {
        double start = omp_get_wtime();
        int **local;
        local = make_array(n,n,0);
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for(j = 0; j <n; ++j)
            {
                local[i][j] = 0;
                #pragma omp for schedule(static)
                for(k = 0; k < n; ++k)
                {
                    local[i][j]+= a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i <n;++i)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                #pragma omp critical
                c[i][j] += local[i][j];
            }
        }
        double end = omp_get_wtime();
        if(TIME < end - start)
        {
            #pragma omp critical
            TIME = end - start;
        }
    }

    printf("%f \n", TIME);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code can be improved, but the problem is elsewhere. Unmodified it runs for 19 seconds on my laptop for 1024x1024 on a single thread and for 10 seconds on two threads. 9,8 seconds on all hyperthreads.

Comment: Care to share what hardware you run this on, what compiler you use, and with what options you compile the code?

Answer (score 0):

This code have *lot of problems*.

The parallelization method is very **inefficient**:

For each possible `i` and `j` you share a very small work to multiple threads. Moreover, there is an *implicit barrier* at the end of the parallel for loop. Thus, the communication between threads takes probably much more time than the actual computation.

The critical sections are usually slow (generally implemented using locks). Here you can replace this by atomic operations.

With k threads, the code need k-time more memory and is likely to be memory bound (because of the cache and more data to be filled, not to mention additional page faults that are expensive nowadays).

As a result, you need to *rework the parallelization method*. You could for example move the `#pragma omp for schedule(static)` on the `i`-based loop. Alternatively, you can divide the matrix in *chunks* and share the work between threads.

Please use **BLAS** libraries to do matrix multiplications. They are much more optimized than this code.

Here is a list of some other problems:

- There are memory leaks (There are `malloc` but no `free`).
- There is a race condition on the `TIME`-based condition.
- Jagged array may be inefficient here compared to flat arrays.

Comment: There is no race condition on `local[i][j]`. The program produces wrong results for a different reason. Also, the arrays are not jagged.

Comment: @HristoIliev There is! Indeed, if i=0 and j=0, then `local[0][0]` is read and written in parallel by multiple threads working on different k values. A reduction is missing. For jagged arrays, they are not usual jagged arrays because in memory it is flat. So I partially agree with you. But still, the compiler see them as jagged array because of the type and they are probably as fast as the common `y*ld+x` pattern on flat arrays here (especially because of the strided access pattern and also if `make_array` is not inlined).

Comment: Look closer. `local` is private. Actually, my statement that the program produces wrong results is incorrect. Only `TIME` may be wrong because there is indeed a race condition.

Comment: Also, given how most compilers implement `schedule(static)`, moving the `for` construct to the `i`-loop doesn't change the amount of OpenMP overhead at all.

Comment: @HristoIliev Good catch for the `local`! I was confused. Sorry.

Comment: @HristoIliev I updated the answer to take into account you comments. Note that `parallel for` loops have an implicit barrier and that moving the for should significantly reduce the amount of barrier (and thus likely the overhead). You can see that [in this example](https://godbolt.org/z/52TLTR) (the `GOMP_barrier` is called a lot of times in the inner loop case, the thing is true for Clang and ICC).

Comment: Yes, but since the threads run in almost lock step, the difference in the barrier overhead is not that pronounced for 1024x1024 (~10% run time for optimised code on my CPU and barely noticeable for unoptimised code). Completely removing it with `nowait` is what makes a big difference.

Comment: @HristoIliev I got a 25% difference on my 6-core skylake processor with a 1024x1024 matrix by just moving the OpenMP directive. This is probably because of the number of cores and the *turbo boost*. I totally agree for the `nowait`.

Comment: The OP states it takes 14 seconds on a single thread. That's definitely code compiled with no optimisation as it takes 5,8 seconds on my Skylake laptop CPU when compiled with `-O1`, so we are definitely in the "barely noticeable OpenMP overhead" zone. I'd put my bet on the culprit being the different sizes of the working set in both cases, as you've noticed too, but we can't know for sure since the OP has provided zero information about the hardware and the compiler options.